# Calculating the highest element in a list and applying this value to all on resize (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a function to calculate height value of the highest element in list and apply this value to all elements in this list.
It works, but not on windows resize. How to force this function running on resize?
Here is the code:

```
var heightEqualizing = function () {
    var element = $('.tm-whatwedo li');

    var elementHeights = element.map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, elementHeights);

    element.height(maxHeight);
    console.log(maxHeight);
};

$(window).resize(heightEqualizing);
$(document).ready(heightEqualizing);
```

Comment: Sounds like what you **really** need is to write a few lines of CSS.

Comment: No, I don't want to use height or min-height. Just would like to calculate height with high precition using javascript to be independent of content.

Comment: Or you could just write CSS that makes them all equal height independent of content. Seriously, you're cutting an onion with a viking war-axe here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      heightEqualizing();
});
```

UPDATE:

Maybe I misunderstand? In this fiddle the window resize event fires the function:
http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/r1obmfh2/

Comment: I tried it before to post this question. Doesn't work.

Comment: Nice, now working. I found a mistake in my changed code. =)  Thanks, camarade!